# structure of $T_\ell A$ for $A/\mathbf{F}_q$ an abelian variety

Tags: etale-cohomology, nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, reference-request

Can someone give me references for the structure of the $G_{\mathbf{F}_q}$-module $T_\ell A$, $A/\mathbf{F}_q$ an abelian variety?

Comment: Mumford's book on abelian varieties?

Comment: The $i$th etale cohomology group is the $i$th wedge power of the 1st, and the 1st is the dual of the Tate module, so if you understand the Tate module then you understand all the etale cohomology.

Comment: If you want to start with the baby case of the Tate module, you can look at Silverman's book (the arithmetic of elliptic curves) where he computes it (it depends whether $l \mid q$ or not)

Comment: Where can I find the description of its *Galois module* structure?

Comment: Mumford's book on abelian varieties?

Comment: I see: The Tate conjecture gives a description of $End_G(T_\ell A)$, in particular of its $G$-automorphisms, in terms of $End(A) \otimes \mathbf{Z}_\ell$.

Comment: But this is not all. Let me think about it.

Comment: OK, $V_\ell A = \mathbf{Q}_\ell^{2g}$, upon which the Frobenius acts semisimply with eigenvalues Weil numbers of weight $-1$.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. For example, if you fix $A$ and let $q$ be large enough, the action is trivial. In general, since the action is continuous and $G_{\mathbf{F}_q}$ is pro-cyclic, you really only need to know the action of Frobenious $\Phi_q$. The characteristic polynomial of $\Phi_q$ is a monic polynomial of degree $2\dim(A)$ with integer coefficients, and its complex roots satisfy $|\alpha|=\sqrt{q}$. Beyond that and duality, the precise action depends on the particular abelian variety and field.

Comment: @unknown: your summary looks good to me (assuming $\ell$ doesn't divide $q$). The char poly of Frobenius has integer coefficients and is independent of $\ell$. That always struck me as amazing. Of course then the Weil conjectures are even more amazing.